# PostgreSQL - SELECT query with ORDER BY and LIMIT 4 very slow, same query much faster with LIMIT >= 40

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, order-by, query-performance

I've got following sample query from our Postgres DB:

```
SELECT * FROM advertised_car a0_ 
LEFT JOIN car_check c1_ ON a0_.car_check_id = c1_.id 
WHERE c1_.status  = 'ACCEPTED'
ORDER BY a0_.id
LIMIT 4;
```

The advertised_car table has about 2M rows, each advertised_car has at most 1 car_check.

The car_check_id is indexed on the advertised_car table. The primary keys and status as well.

**This query is extremely slow** - over 1s. 
When I remove either the limit or order by clause, I get a result under 0.05s.

I suppose that since the results are filtered, the DB cannot utilize existing index on a0_.id and has to reorder all the results.

What I don't get is the fact that when calling this query:

```
SELECT * FROM advertised_car a0_ 
LEFT JOIN car_check c1_ ON a0_.car_check_id = c1_.id 
WHERE c1_.status  = 'ACCEPTED'
ORDER BY a0_.id
LIMIT 40;
```

The **query suddenly runs much faster**, almost as fast as without LIMIT or ORDER BY clause.

The execution plans differ, but I don't understand why the index scan in the first plan takes so long

Full execution plans:

LIMIT 4:  https://pastebin.com/azvxT0ZY

LIMIT 40: https://pastebin.com/yABqQVCa

Visual:

[image: The execution plan:]

Comment: Are you sure this is not due to some caching effect, i.e. what happens if you run the queries in the opposite order?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely not caching. I've tried to run the same queries countless times. The query plan is simply very different. After running VACUUM ANALYZE, the LIMIT when the query optimizer starts to use the second query has raised to about 100 but the results are the same.